# Correlations between response (NDVI) and explanatory (certain precipitation months) variables in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation

I am trying to correlate ndvi of certain months (jul, aug, sept) to the coefficient of variation (cv) of the previous 6 months.

My original dataset "d" includes monthly ndvi and precipitation data for 13 years for 26 stations:

```
  row.names timestamp  station      year   month   ndvi  landcover    altitude precipitation
1         1         1      A            2000   jan   0.4138  Mixed forest     2143          16.0
2      1769         2      A            2000   feb   0.4396  Mixed forest     2143           4.0
```

So far I have the following script that allows me to correlate and plot just the precipitation in months jan-jun to the ndvi in jul.

```
for(m in c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun")) {
  ndvi<-d$ndvi[d$month=="jul"]
  precip<-d$precipitation[d$month==m]
  r2<-cor(ndvi,precip)^2
  cat("month =",m,"P=",cor.test(ndvi,precip)$p.value,"\n")
  plot(ndvi~precip,main=m, sub=sprintf("r2=%.2f",r2))
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can incorporate the cv of jan-jun into the for loop?

```
d$cv <- sd(d$precipitation, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(d$precipitation, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

@Osssan I tried to input your changes like this:

```
for(m in c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun")) {
  ndvi<-d$ndvi[d$month=="aug"]
  precip_6m<-d$precipitation[d$month %in% c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun")]  
  cv= sd(precip_6m, na.rm=TRUE)/mean(precip_6m,na.rm=TRUE)
  r2<-cor(ndvi,cv, use="complete.obs")^2
  cat("month =",m,"P=",cor.test(ndvi,cv, na.action=na.omit)$p.value,"\n")
  plot(ndvi~cv,main=m,
      sub=sprintf("r2=%.2f",r2))
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Error in cor(ndvi, cv, use = "complete.obs") : incompatible dimensions
```

Basically for every year 2000-2013, I need to have the R squared, plot and p values of the coefficient of variation (jan-jun: ONE value) vs. NDVI (separately for jul/aug/sep).

Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful to know what `a` and `r` are, and why you dataset `d` doesn't appear in your loop.

Comment: `precip_6m<-a$precipitation[a$month %in% c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun")]`  and `cv= sd(precip_6m,...)/mean(precip_6m,...)` , is this what you are looking for

Comment: @rbatt sorry, please replace a with d and ignore the r (just to show how i calculated cv - taken from another script)

Comment: before trying to solve for N years, I suggest subset your data for one year, execute all the steps (r2,plot,...) and when you are satisfied combine it in a loop